# How to plot rectangle/bounding box in R?

Tags: r, r-sp

How do I generate a box rather than the hourglass shape this code is returning? I've tried changing the order of the coordinates but always have that "x" forming rather than a box, sometimes as a sideways hourglass.

```
library(sp)
mybb <- cbind(x=c(363498.5,480497.5,363498.5, 480497.5,363498.5), y=c(5894630,5894630,5806524,5806524,5894630))
crs <-CRS("+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
mybb <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(mybb)),"1")), proj4string=crs)
plot(mybb)
```

Returns:

[image: Coordinates not plotted as a rectangle/box]

Comment: Please start the script with a call to `library(pkgname)` to load the package where functions `CRS`, `SpatialPolygons`, etc are to be found.

Comment: Sorry, I should know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why rearranging the coordinates hasn't worked so far. This worked for me.

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

mybb <- cbind(x=c(363498.5, 480497.5, 480497.5, 363498.5), y=c(5894630, 5894630, 5806524, 5806524))
crs <-CRS("+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
mybb <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(mybb)),"1")), proj4string=crs)
plot(mybb)
```

Comment: Thanks! For others, this is the order coordinate pairs should be written, where TL = top left, RB = right bottom etc. referring to vertices of a rectangle: 1) TL, 2) TR, 3) BR, 4) BL, optionally 5) TL to close (clockwise)